# Android Mapview panning and zooming too slow

Tags: android, android-mapview

I've developed a `GPS` app in which i record the user roots and show it
on the map.......but
Panning around on the map when reviewing my route is painfully slow,
it takes at least 4 or 5 seconds for the map to respond the finger
swipes......

I've overridden the `onDraw()`  method and drawing the lines to show the
routes......is there any better way to do this so that panning becomes
faster as in `"MyTracks"`...........

Thank you all.....
Pratap S.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do [something similar](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dalelane/4584648479/). My attempt currently does the following in onDraw (*simplified for readability - error-handling etc. stripped out*):

```
if ((bmap == null) || (lastZoom != mapv.getLatitudeSpan()))
{
    // bitmap is null - so we haven't previously drawn the path, OR
    //  the map has been zoomed in/out, so we're gonna re-draw it anyway
    //    (alternatively, I could have tried scaling the bitmap... might
    //     be worth investigating if that is more efficient)

    Projection proj = mapv.getProjection();

    // store zoom level for comparing in the next onDraw
    lastZoom = mapv.getLatitudeSpan();

    // draw a path of all of the points in my route
    GeoPoint start = routePoints.get(0);
    Point startPt = new Point();            
    proj.toPixels(start, startPt);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(startPt.x, startPt.y);

    Point nxtPt;

    for (GeoPoint nextPoint : routePoints) 
    {
        nxtPt = new Point();
        proj.toPixels(nextPoint, nxtPt);
        path.lineTo(nxtPt.x, nxtPt.y);
    }

    // create a new bitmap, the size of the map view
    bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapv.getWidth(), mapv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // create an off-screen canvas to prepare new bitmap, and draw path on to it
    Canvas offscreencanvas = new Canvas(bmap);
    offscreencanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);

    // draw the bitmap of the path onto my map view's canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, 0, 0, null);

    // make a note of where we put the bitmap, so we know how much we 
    //  we need to move it by if the user pans the map
    mapStartPosition = proj.fromPixels(0, 0);
}
else
{
    // as we're in onDraw, we think the user has panned/moved the map
    //  if we're in here, the zoom level hasn't changed, and
    //   we've already got a bitmap with a drawing of the route path

    Projection proj = mapv.getProjection();

    // where has the mapview been panned to?
    Point offsetPt = new Point();
    proj.toPixels(mapStartPosition, offsetPt);

    // draw the bitmap in the new correct location
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, offsetPt.x, offsetPt.y, null);
}
```

It's not perfect yet.... for example, the path ends up in the wrong place immediately after zooming - being moved to the correct place once the user starts panning.

But it's a start - and hugely more efficient than redrawing the path on every onDraw call

Hope this helps!

Comment: Has anyone ever figured out the zooming thing? I've been wrestling this monster on-and-off for 10months.

Answer (score 2):

Comment to dalelane's answer from May,7th:
I used your solution for reducing the load of drawing, but modified it a bit:

- a new bitmap is created, if the map center, the zoom levelhave cjanged or no old bitmap exists.

After zooming the route is placed on the correct position. It seems that zooming has not finished completely, when a changed zoom level is detected.

I used a timer, which modifies the map center by 10 after a delay of 600 msecs after the zoom level changed.
By changing the map center the draw method is called and creates a new bitmap. The route then is placed correctly.
 This is an ugly work around. Has anyone a better solution?

```
private void panAfterZoom(MapView mv, long delay){
    timer = new java.util.Timer("drawtimer", true);
    mapView=mv;
    task = new java.util.TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
           GeoPoint center=mapView.getMapCenter();
           GeoPoint point=new GeoPoint(center.getLatitudeE6()+10, center.getLongitudeE6());
           MapController contr=mapView.getController();
           contr.setCenter(point);
           timer.cancel();
       }
       };
    timer.schedule(task, delay);
}
```

This is called in the draw method as: pabAfterZoom(mapView, 600);

Bost

Answer (score 1):

**My thanks to dalelane**, who's proposal above helped me improving my route overlay.
I would like to share an improvement that solves the problem with path ending in the wrong place after a zoom change.

**Problem root cause:**
The mapview.getLatitudeSpan() as well as the mapview.getZoomLevel() methods return the values not taking into consideration the progressive map scale variation (animation) between to zoom values.

**Solution:**
The method mapview.getProjection().fromPixels(x,y) take this progressive variation into account, so you can build your getLatitudeSpan() or getLongitudeSpan() from it, and the route will always display correctly.

Below is the dalelane proposed code with the changes made:

```
**int lonSpanNew = mapv.getProjection().fromPixels(0,mapv.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6() - mapv.getProjection().fromPixels(mapv.getWidth(),mapview.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6();**
if ((bmap == null) || (lastZoom != **lonSpanNew** )) 
{ 
    // bitmap is null - so we haven't previously drawn the path, OR 
    //  the map has been zoomed in/out, so we're gonna re-draw it anyway 
    //    (alternatively, I could have tried scaling the bitmap... might 
    //     be worth investigating if that is more efficient) 

    Projection proj = mapv.getProjection(); 

    // store zoom level for comparing in the next onDraw 
    lastZoom = **lonSpanNew**;  

    // draw a path of all of the points in my route 
    GeoPoint start = routePoints.get(0); 
    Point startPt = new Point();             
    proj.toPixels(start, startPt); 

    Path path = new Path(); 
    path.moveTo(startPt.x, startPt.y); 

    Point nxtPt; 

    for (GeoPoint nextPoint : routePoints)  
    { 
        nxtPt = new Point(); 
        proj.toPixels(nextPoint, nxtPt); 
        path.lineTo(nxtPt.x, nxtPt.y); 
    } 

    // create a new bitmap, the size of the map view 
    bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapv.getWidth(), mapv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    // create an off-screen canvas to prepare new bitmap, and draw path on to it 
    Canvas offscreencanvas = new Canvas(bmap); 
    offscreencanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint); 

    // draw the bitmap of the path onto my map view's canvas 
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, 0, 0, null); 

    // make a note of where we put the bitmap, so we know how much we  
    //  we need to move it by if the user pans the map 
    mapStartPosition = proj.fromPixels(0, 0); 
} 
else 
{ 
    // as we're in onDraw, we think the user has panned/moved the map 
    //  if we're in here, the zoom level hasn't changed, and 
    //   we've already got a bitmap with a drawing of the route path 

    Projection proj = mapv.getProjection(); 

    // where has the mapview been panned to? 
    Point offsetPt = new Point(); 
    proj.toPixels(mapStartPosition, offsetPt); 

    // draw the bitmap in the new correct location 
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, offsetPt.x, offsetPt.y, null); 
}
```

Hope this help.
Regards,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Overriding onDraw would be the only way.  How are you drawing the tracks, maybe that can be made more efficient?